# Agregar useState en checkbox en un ciclo for react

Tags: array, reactjs, react-hooks, checkbox

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion sencilla en react que es una lista de tareas. Simplemente recibe en un input el nombre y crea un elemento en el localstorage y despues lo muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucede que en el checkbox de la izquierda quiero que cuando este activo la tarea se de por completada cambiandole estilos en css, esto no es problematico, el problema es que estoy usando un useState para agregarselo a los checkbox que estan en una lista.

Componente:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { TaskModal } from './TaskModal';

export const TaskList = ({ list, setList }) => {
    
    const labelText = useRef();
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false); //state del checkbox
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [indTask, setIndTask] = useState({});
    
    const deleteTask = (e, task) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newList = list.filter(t => t.title !== task.title);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(newList));
        setList(newList);
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCheck(!check);
    };

    const handleShow = (e, task) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIndTask(task);
        setShow(true);
    }
    
  return (
    <div className='list-container'>
        {list !== [] && list.map((task, idx) => (
            <div className='task-container' key={task.title}>
                <input 
                    className='done-task' 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    name='check' //nombre del state
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, task, idx)} 
                    checked={check} //valor del state 
                />
                <label htmlFor="" ref={labelText} onClick={(e) => handleShow(e, task)} className='task' >{task.title}</label> 
                <button className='delete-task' onClick={(e) => deleteTask(e, task)}>
                    <i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        ))}
        {show && <TaskModal task={indTask} list={list} setList={setList} setShow={setShow} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Sucede que cuando le doy en el checkbox, el state cambia de una forma extraña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que la que deberia cambiar es el primer checkbox(el que esta en rojo) pero cambia es el siguiente y en el segundo cambia el primero entonces no se como solucionarlo, pienso que es por el state que esta repetido asi que agradezco el que tenga una solucion a este problema Gracias.

Comment: Si pudieras compartir un repositorio, cuando hay listas con checkboxes lo ideal es tener una bandera de estatus en el estado para cada elemento de dicha lista.